# Why isn't my port exposed? netstat output included

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-compose, netstat

This is my problem

```
# docker exec -ti root_web_1 bash
[root@ca32f79bdc14]# curl couchdb:5984
curl: (7) Failed to connect to couchdb port 5984: Connection refused
[root@ca32f79bdc14]# curl redis:6379  
-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
-ERR unknown command 'Host:'
-ERR unknown command 'User-Agent:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept:'
^C
```

**Question**

Why can't I access `couchdb:5984` ?

**Background**

When I am in my couchdb container I can `curl localhost:5984` and it responds and `netstat -nl` gives me

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35300        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:51267        0.0.0.0:*
```

and the `Dockerfile` contains `EXPOSE 5984`, but I get `connection refused` when doing `curl couchdb:5984` from the `web` container.

When I do the same with redis, `curl redis:6379` it responds and `netstat -nl` gives

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:46665        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:49518        0.0.0.0:*
```

This is the couchdb `Dockerfile`

```
FROM fedora:25
RUN dnf -y update
RUN dnf -y install couchdb
EXPOSE 5984
CMD ["/usr/bin/couchdb"]
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '2'
networks:
  revproxynet:
    external: true
services:
  web:
    images: nginx
    networks:
      - revproxynet
  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - revproxynet
  couchdb:
    build: /docker/couchdb/
    networks:
      - revproxynet
```

The network is created with `docker network create revproxynet`.

Comment: IMHO this is off-topic here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/etc/couchdb/local.ini` you need to have

```
[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

and it will work.